# Branching Process for when $Y_0$=3

Tags: probability

Consider a branching process $Y_0$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$ . . . starting with one ancestor,
that is Y0 = 1. Suppose that the generating random variable X of this process and $Gx(t)=($2t/3$ + $1/3$)^2$,
Find the probability of extinction now, if Y0=3

I managed to find the probability of extinction when $Y_0=1$ but I don't know where to start here. I thought about thinking back to the definition of the branching process and thought about substituting $Y_0=3$ but I didn't know how to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process starts with 3 individuals then the family tress of all three ancestors have to be extinct in order that the whole process is extinct. The tress evolving from the three individuals evolve independently of each other. So the extinction probability is simply $q^{3}$ where $q$ is the extinction probability for $Y_0=1$.